# Angular JS submit button enable disable on $invalid

Tags: angularjs

I am enabling and disabling submit button in my form based upon $invalid.
i have two dates in my form start date and end date. how/Where should i set $invalid to true or false

code snippet:

```
<p ng-show="formName.endTime <= formName.startTime " class="help-block">
  <img src="img/warn.png">End Date should always be greater than Start Date.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you please see demo here http://plnkr.co/edit/msVjtQsqUFMuRliIMwVC?p=preview
In this case you have to do check formName.$invalid
like

```
<form name="myForm" ng-controller="FormController" class="my-form">
 from: <input name='fromDate' type='date' ng-model="fromDate" required> 
  to: <input type="date" name="toDate" ng-model="toDate" required>
 <input type="submit" ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I want to put a check that if 'end date' is less than the 'start date' then submit button should be disabled, which is not happening in your demo